# sc command doesn't take directory path with space

Tags: wix

Using the below command I couldn't change the directory path with space in my wix installer. New Folder is the directory path which contains space. I am using wix 3.8.

```
sc create "Video player" binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\Video\Storage\\pgsql\bin\pg_ctl.exe\" runservice -N \"Video player\" -D C:\ProgramData\Video\Storage\Database\New Folder\  -w" start= auto obj= "NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" password= ""  1>>db_service_install.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes in -D parameter, so command line takes it only as `-D C:\ProgramData\Video\Storage\Database\New` , because of the space in folder name (command line arguments are delimeted by space).

`-D "C:\ProgramData\Video\Storage\Database\New Folder"` should do the trick